# Sigma-algebra generated by conditional expectation

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables, conditional-expectation, measurable-functions

I am dealing with the following question: given two dependent random variables $X_1,X_2$, I am wondering whether the following equivalence for the generated sigma-algebras holds:

1. $$\sigma(X_1)=\sigma(X_1 + c) $$
2. $$\sigma(X_1,X_2)=\sigma(X_1 + c,X_2+\mathbb{E}[X_2|X_1])$$

where $c$ is a known constant.

For the first one. I am pretty sure that it holds, as the heuristic is telling us: on LHS "I know" $X_1$ and on the RHS "I know" $X_1$ up to a known constant.

For the second one: the conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}[X_2|X_1]$ is $\sigma(X_1)$-measurable, i.e.

$$ \sigma(\mathbb{E}[X_2|X_1]) \subset \sigma(X_1)$$

and it can be written as $f(X_1)$ a.s., where $f$ is Borel measurable.
So what we need to show is that

$$\sigma(X_1,X_2)=\sigma(X_1 + c,X_2+f(X_1))$$

But as $f$ is deterministic, and given 1., this means that 2. holds, if the following holds

$$\sigma(X_1,X_2)=\sigma(X_1,X_2+X_1)$$

which looks correct to me.

Am I right? Is it enough to say that 2. holds?

I have tried to write it formally with sets but I did not manage to find evidence of 2. At the same time I have not been able to find a counterexample. Any hint or idea would be helpful.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: $f(X_1)$ is not deterministic.

Comment: Are they dependent or independent ? If they are dependent, then I think the result is false if you take $X_2 = -X_1$ almost surely for instance.

Comment: @StratosFair  1) and 2) are both true in your case.

Comment: Thank you both for the contributions. I think the answer by @geetha290krm gives evidence of the equality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\sigma(X_1)=\sigma(X_1 + c) $ follows from the fact that $(X_1+c)^{-1}(A)=X_1^{-1}(A-c)$ for any Borel set $A$: $A$ is Borel if and only if $A-c$ is Borel.

It is trivial to check that $\sigma(X_1 + c,X_2+\mathbb{E}[X_2|X_1]) \subseteq \sigma(X_1,X_2)$. For the reverse inclusion we have to show that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are measurable w.r.t. $\sigma(X_1 + c,X_2+\mathbb{E}[X_2|X_1])$. For $X_1$ this is clear. For $X_2$ here is a hint: use the equation $X_2=(X_2+\mathbb{E}[X_2|X_1])- g(X_1+c)$ where $g$ is a measurable function such that $\mathbb{E}[X_2|X_1])=g(X_1+c)$. [Can you see why $g$ exists?].

Comment: If I am not wrong, $g$ exists by definition of conditional expectation, i.e. it is a version of the conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}[X_2|X_1+c]$. So by your representation of $X_2$ and point 1. I can deduce the measurability of $X_2$ respect to the sigma algebra generated by $(X_1+c,X_2+\mathbb{E}[X_2|X_1])$. An it is exactly what I was missing. Thank you very much!